# How to rig separate object to specific bones?

Tags: rigging, rigify

I'm having issues, the hair is just a hair curve with geo node applied on it for thickness, I have a child of constraint added to it to follow the rig's neck or head bone, when I move the neck or head though I have issues with it slipping, is there a way I can make it so the hair doesn't slip at all, and works as if I parented it thru object mode, is there a way to have like the hair and the head bone work as if like I had parented the head object to the head object in object mode, have same location and no slipping

[image]

EDIT: I'm also having issues with scaling the whole model, I was going to use this model in another blender file but appending it and trying to scale to match my other scene I get most of the characters properties just scaled and randomly moved too much, how can I fix that as well?

[image]

Comment: do u want it like this? [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVNRu.gif

Comment: YESS that's exactly what I am looking for

Comment: Is there a reason why when I try to scale the whole object with head and body I get weird deformations? how can I fix that when I scale it also keeps the models location and stuff intact?

Comment: just scale the whole armature in object mode. Your head isn't rigged, so you have to rig the head too first.

Answer (score 0):

I've removed the head object from the surface of the hairs and then I added the `Chid Of` constraints and target to `Rig head`.

For the scale of the object, I added another `Child of` constraint to the objects to follow the head.

[image]

Here you go!
[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. delete the child of constraint of you hair + surface deform modifier
2. parent your hair to the "Neck" bone

[image]